# Cucumber not working on my machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

Cucumber is somehow not working on my machine. Now on running

```
bundle show cucumber
```

I am getting

```
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.0.6
```

but when I now try to run the features on my application I am getting the following error

```
bundle exec cucumber features

Using the default profile...
no such file to load -- crack/core_extensions (LoadError)
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/pusher-0.6.0/lib/pusher/channel.rb:1
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/pusher-0.6.0/lib/pusher.rb:67
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require'
/Users/gauravsingharoy/work/tiatros/config/application.rb:7
/Users/gauravsingharoy/work/tiatros/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
/Users/gauravsingharoy/work/tiatros/config/environment.rb:2
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-rails-1.0.2/lib/cucumber/rails.rb:5:in `require'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-rails-1.0.2/lib/cucumber/rails.rb:5
/Users/gauravsingharoy/work/tiatros/features/support/env.rb:7:in `require'
/Users/gauravsingharoy/work/tiatros/features/support/env.rb:7
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.0.6/bin/../lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:143:in `load'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.0.6/bin/../lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:143:in `load_code_file'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.0.6/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:171:in `load_file'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.0.6/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `load_files!'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.0.6/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `each'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.0.6/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `load_files!'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.0.6/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:137:in `load_step_definitions'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.0.6/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:39:in `run!'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.0.6/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:43:in `execute!'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.0.6/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-1.0.6/bin/cucumber:14
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bin/cucumber:19:in `load'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bin/cucumber:19
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REF FOR INSTALLING RVM: 
http://seanbehan.com/mac-os-x/installing-and-using-rvm-on-mac-os-x-creating-gemsets-and-reverting-to-original-environment/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like bundler can't find your dependencies. You appear to be using a System-wide ruby installation which is unrecommended.

I recommend you install rvm and reinstall ruby using rvm's method then running bundle again once everything is configured and working correctly.